# What do the different levels Sentinel activity mean?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In my travels I've seen many levels of Sentinel activity(I don't know if this is the correct word, I'll edit if I'm wrong) when I discover planets. They've ranged from low to average I've even seen relaxed and normal. This is confusing to me, as there are different words for entries that, in my mind, would be the same "level" of activity.

**What are the different levels of Sentinel activity, and how do the affect the Sentinel's behavior?**

Comment: I suspect they're using words that mean the same thing just to add variety, but I can't prove it. You see something similar when looking at animal traits or the climate (wintry and crisp both translate to cold). It's just an atmosphere thing, I think.

Answer (score 3):

The levels indicate how much provocation is required before the sentinels will attack. Sentinels are provoked by killing animals, mining resources, or destroying reinforced objects or resource caches.

For example, on more permissive planets, you can kill an animal and get away with it, even if a sentinel sees. On stricter planets, they can get provoked by simply mining a large number of resources in front of them.

I believe it is also linked to how strong of a response you get once they begin attacking you. A stronger response can mean both a greater number of attacking sentinels and deadlier sentinels. There are powerful, ground-based sentinels that will show up when they get really mad.

On planets with the highest levels of activity (like *Aggressive* or *Frenzied*), your presence is provocation enough. Sentinels will attack on sight and immediately call in support.

It's worth noting that there is a correlation between sentinel activity and valuable resources. The sentinels' role is to protect nature, and what the player considers "rare", they consider "endangered".

Comment: This sounds correct, but do you have a source to confirm this is indeed the case?

Comment: My answer is initially sourced in my experience with the game. The difference in behavior is pretty visible once you visit the stricter planets, or kill animals at the different levels. I was able to find game wikis that agree with my answer, but do wikis count as a source?

Comment: +1 to this answer. I've stepped on planets with aggressive sentinels and have been attacked immediately on-sight for no reason whatsoever. [There is another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280916/what-makes-sentinels-hostile) that talks about hostile Sentinels that can also backup this answer.

Comment: Note also that regardless of their activity level, or whether there are any around to see it, when you find a structure with a locked door that prompts you to shoot it (i.e. not those that need a pass), a sentinel will always spawn with aggression towards you after the 2nd or 3rd bullet hits.

Comment: This is a good answer to the second half of the question, but totally ignores the first half. If you add something to address that, even if it's incomplete, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It doesn't even really answer the second part.  I want and need a list, an actual list, of all the classes, and what they actually mean.  I'm somewhere right now where the sentinels are "unwavering".  It doesn't tell how many / how frequent they are, and it doesn't even tell me how aggresive they are, just that they are "unwavering" (which I understand to mean they won't back down… but they never do anyway, so what does that even *mean*)